# 4TB hard disk on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: hard-disk, raspberry-pi

I never had problems with USB drives before,
but this new 4TB by WD I'm unable to make it recognized.
I created a single ext4 partition (GPT).
I tried both connecting it directly, and also via a powered USB hub.

This is my dmesg output:

```
 [    9.524932] usb 1-1.5.4.2: new low-speed USB device number 8 using dwc_otg
[    9.621425] usb 1-1.5.4.2: New USB device found, idVendor=20a0, idProduct=0001
[    9.621455] usb 1-1.5.4.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    9.621471] usb 1-1.5.4.2: Product: flirc
[    9.621485] usb 1-1.5.4.2: Manufacturer: flirc.tv
[    9.628973] input: flirc.tv flirc as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5.4/1-1.5.4.2/1-1.5.4.2:1.0/0003:20A0:0001.0002/input/input1
[    9.683189] hid-generic 0003:20A0:0001.0002: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.01 Keyboard [flirc.tv flirc] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.5.4.2/input0
[    9.745199] rtl8192c_dm_RF_Saving(): RF_Save
[    9.853153]  ~~~~set sta key:groupkey
[    9.853192] ==> rtw_set_key algorithm(4),keyid(2),key_mask(0)
[    9.861231] SetHwReg8192CU, 5128, RCR= 700060ce 
[   10.525606] OnAction_back
[   10.525652] OnAction_back, action=0
[   10.525672] issue_action_BA, category=3, action=1, status=0
[   22.396077] usb 1-1.5.4.2: USB disconnect, device number 8
[   23.861616] usb 1-1.5.4.2: new low-speed USB device number 9 using dwc_otg
[   23.949219] usb 1-1.5.4.2: New USB device found, idVendor=20a0, idProduct=0001
[   23.949250] usb 1-1.5.4.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   23.949268] usb 1-1.5.4.2: Product: flirc
[   23.949282] usb 1-1.5.4.2: Manufacturer: flirc.tv
[   23.965104] input: flirc.tv flirc as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5.4/1-1.5.4.2/1-1.5.4.2:1.0/0003:20A0:0001.0003/input/input2
[   24.019506] hid-generic 0003:20A0:0001.0003: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.01 Keyboard [flirc.tv flirc] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.5.4.2/input0
[   44.351608] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 10 using dwc_otg
[   45.287782] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=25e2
[   45.287821] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[   45.287837] usb 1-1.2: Product: My Passport 25E2
[   45.287851] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[   45.287868] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 575836314435385041315631
[   45.294105] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   45.294658] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[   46.299736] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Passport 25E2 4005 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[   46.304519] scsi 0:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       4005 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[   46.305303] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unit Not Ready
[   46.305345] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : 0x4 [current] 
[   46.305365] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[  226.377178] sd 0:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those last four lines are the relevant part here.

> `[   46.305303] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unit Not Ready`

This says that the drive reports as not being ready.

> `[   46.305345] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : 0x4 [current]`

`Sense Key : 0x4` indicates an unrecoverable hardware-level error during a rive self-test.

> `[   46.305365] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81`

This line gives info on the exact error.  I don't recognize ASC code 0x44, so I unfortunately can't give a certain answer on this.

> `[  226.377178] sd 0:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s`

This means that the kernel timed out waiting for a response to a command it issued to the drive.  Given the above mentioned hardware error, it probably gave up after the first try.

Taken altogether, this means that the drive reported a hardware-level error it couldn't recover from, and the kernel gave up trying to talk to it because of this.

Given that it's a USB connected drive, my first suggestion would be verifying that it's getting sufficient power.  If it's a conventional hard drive, it will almost certainly draw more than the 500mA at 5V that can be supplied safely across all USB ports by a Pi.  I would suggest double checking the cabling, making sure you have the drive connected through a powered external hub, and trying again.  If that still fails, there may be something wrong with the drive itself.

---

As a slight aside, be *very* careful using USB for any kind of long-term fixed storage.  The fact that you have had no issues prior to this just means your lucky, not that USB is reliable, especially since most filesystems don't actually report any errors caused by it even when they do happen.  This type of long-term usage involving high-volume bulk data transfers is not something USB itself was designed for, and as a result, a *lot* of USB hardware just doesn't work reliably for this type of usage.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. For completeness I add that the drive is working perfectly when connected to my linux desktop PC, so the insufficient current must be the reason. I will have to check how much the powered hub is able to give (though I dont know exactly how...)

Comment: @alessandro As a general rule, most good powered USB hubs will have the max current they can source written on them somewhere.  If not, the safe assumption is typically 50-80% of what the power supply for the hub is rated for in terms of wattage (so, multiply the voltage and current listed on the power supply, then divide by 5 (the standard USB voltage).  The other possibility though is that the hub itself might be causing problems for the disk, so you might consider checking that the disk works through that specific hub on your PC too.